# Photos from last gallery

Tags: mysql

I have galleries and photos in all galleries.

Is possible "in only one query" to list the photos of last the gallery? The last gallery is the most recently date

For example:

table "gallery" with field "data" and table "fotos" with fields "file" and "gallery_fk"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE gallery_fk = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM gallery);
```

Assuming your gallery-table has an id-field (which would refer to "gallery_fk" in table "fotos") to retrieve whatever you mean with "last gallery", here the highest id would be the "last gallery" (otherwise you could add a date-field and select the "latest" from that).

Answer (score 1):

By using a *sub select* and **MySql LIMIT** (*Sql Server TOP*), you can try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT *
            FROM Galeries
            ORDER BY 
            DATE DESC 
            LIMIT 1
        ) LatestGalery INNER JOIN
        Fotos f ON LatestGalery.GaleryID = f.GaleryID
```